# ROR - scatter graph - how to add background image?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

Not sure this question is allowed here. I am not looking for an opinion but an answer on how to approach this.  I am scratching my head where to find help on technically how to approach this.-  not sure where else to look for it.

Rails 6.0
tailwindcss
stimulusjs

Here is my question:

I am plotting 2 axis of data (plan to use Chartkick & scattergraph).  Once I plot them, I want to show them against a background image.  I want to do it on a background like this?

[https://monosnap.com/file/4NNH3y9nOPxXFaClg661DQBw6ujyBe]

I am a novice on CSS.  Is it just straight CSS?  What is best approach to this?  Raw CSS?  Plugin? other?

Comment: You can create that sort of background-image using a linear-gradient in CSS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer....  that looks easy and should do the job. thank you so much.